# Working webrtc chat sample

Tags: webrtc

Please propose some working demo of webrtc text chat. Tried googling alot, but result usually leads to this one: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/chat-hangout/ or commercial opensource software. https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/chat-hangout/ doesn't work for me. Are there any other working opensource demos of webrtc chats?

Thanx.

Comment: Please try this instead: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RTCMultiConnection/MultiRTC/ It is open-sourced here: https://github.com/muaz-khan/MultiRTC

Comment: @MuazKhan Thanx, it works. But i need text chat. If you provide working webrtc text chat, I'll accept your answer. Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a live-demo for Text-Chat + file sharing:

- https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/demos/TextChat+FileSharing.html

Here is the source-code:

- https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/blob/master/RTCMultiConnection-v3.0/demos/TextChat%2BFileSharing.html

Please disable following line if you don't want file sharing:

```
connection.enableFileSharing = true;
```

RTCMultiConnection is a big library, which is NOT for those who wanna understand WebRTC codes.

If you're learning WebRTC, then I'll suggest readthis this post:

- https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/how-to-use-rtcdatachannel.html

Above post will explain how to create one-to-one data connection (text chat connection) between two users.

There is another post that explains how to implement mesh networking model to support text-chat between multiple users:

- https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/how-to-WebRTC-video-conferencing.html

Many other relevant tutorials can be found here:

- https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/

If you're looking for a good chat solution with socket.io fallback:

- https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-p2p

Comment: first two links outdated, is it your project?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a text chat or an audio/video chat? Or do you need both?

WebRTC is used for building audio/video chat. 
For text chat XMPP is popular.

Here is a demo of text chat: http://connectycube.com/samples/sample-chat-browser

And here is a demo of audio/video chat built on top of WebRTC: https://connectycube.com/samples/sample-videochat-browser/

Code samples can be found here: https://developers.connectycube.com/js/code-samples

Comment: Unfortunately, It's 404 now

Answer (score 0):

Several years ago I developed WebRTC/SignalR chat.

You can see code [on github](https://github.com/alexan1/SignalRTC).

And [web application](https://signalrtc.com/).